# How to compare dates in LINQ?

Tags: .net, linq

I want to check if a given date is more than a month earlier than today's date using LINQ.

What is the syntax for this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I assume that you're talking about in the where clause.  It's basically the same way you would compare two DateTime objects elsewhere.

```
using (DataContext context = new DataContext()) {
   var query = from t in context.table
               where t.CreateDate.Date < DateTime.Today.AddMonths(-1)
               select t;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Just to add, in LINQ To Entities you have to compare to a variable. Example:

```
        DateTime lastMonth = DateTime.Today.AddMonths(-1);
        using (var db = new MyEntities())
        {
            var query = from s in db.ViewOrTable
                        orderby s.ColName
                        where (s.StartDate > lastMonth)
                        select s;

            _dsResults = query.ToList();
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want your code to throw

```
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime AddYears(Int32)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
```

I would suggest using DbFunctions.AddYears. Also, if you are concerned only about dates and not the times, you could use DbFunctions.TruncateTime

Something like this-

```
DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.date) ==
DbFunctions.TruncateTime(DbFunctions.AddYears(DateTime.Today, 1))
```